# Use of randomforest() for classification in R?

Tags: r, random-forest

I originally had a data frame composed of 12 columns in N rows. The last column is my class (0 or 1). I had to convert my entire data frame to numeric with

```
training <- sapply(training.temp,as.numeric)
```

But then I thought I needed the class column to be a factor column to use the randomforest() tool as a classifier, so I did

```
training[,"Class"] <- factor(training[,ncol(training)])
```

I proceed to creating the tree with

```
training_rf <- randomForest(Class ~., data = trainData, importance = TRUE, do.trace = 100)
```

But I'm getting two errors:

```
1: In Ops.factor(training[, "Status"], factor(training[, ncol(training)])) : 
<= this is not relevant for factors (roughly translated)
2: In randomForest.default(m, y, ...) :
The response has five or fewer unique values.  Are you sure you want to do regression?
```

I would appreciate it if someone could point out the formatting mistake I'm making.

Thanks!

Comment: you are trying to use `<=` for assignment instead of `<-`. Also are you creating a new column? if so you should get rid of the numeric version of `Class` or not use `.` in your formula

Comment: The only information that can settle this question is the output from `str(training)`.

Comment: @joran: num [1:891, 1:12] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:12] "ID" "Class" "Sex" "Age" ...

Comment: Don't put stuff like that in comments. As you can see, it doesn't fit. Edit your question and format it properly.

Comment: @JakeBurkhead: That was indeed where the first error was coming from.

Comment: Is `trainData` the same as `training`?

Comment: The second error (I think its just a warning) is showing up because `Class` in `trainData` is `numeric` but has fewer than 5 unique values. Since it is `numeric` `randomForest` is attempting regression, but you want classification so you need `Class` to be a factor, which it should be if you fix the first error and `trainData` is just a copy of `training`

Answer (score 8):

So the issue is actually quite simple. It turns out my training data was an atomic vector. So it first had to be converted as a data frame. So I needed to add the following line:

```
training <- as.data.frame(training)
```

Problem solved!

Answer (score 6):

First, your coercion to a factor is not working because of syntax errors. Second, you should always use indexing when specifying a RF model. Here are changes in your code that should make it work.

```
    training <- sapply(training.temp,as.numeric)
      training[,"Class"] <- as.factor(training[,"Class"])

    training_rf <- randomForest(x=training[,1:(ncol(training)-1)], y=training[,"Class"], 
                                importance=TRUE, do.trace=100)

# You can also coerce to a factor directly in the model statement
    training_rf <- randomForest(x=training[,1:(ncol(training)-1)], y=as.factor(training[,"Class"]), 
                                importance=TRUE, do.trace=100)
```

Comment: This didn't solve my problem, it's still asking me if I want to do a regression...

Comment: I ended up using this syntax once I added the line that I just posted.