# Why does Random Forest regression in R not like my input data?

Tags: r, vector, dataframe, random-forest

I'm trying a very simple random forest, as shown below:  The code is entirely self-contained and runnable.

```
library(randomForest)
n = 1000

factor=10
x1 = seq(n) + rnorm(n, 0, 150)
y = x1*factor + rnorm(n, 0, 550)

x_data = data.frame(x1)
y_data = data.frame(y)

k=2
for (nfold in seq(k)){
  fold_ids <- cut(seq(1, nrow(x_data)), breaks=k, labels=FALSE)
  id_indices <- which(fold_ids==nfold)
  fold_x <- x_data[id_indices,]
  fold_y <- y_data[id_indices,]
  fold_x_df = data.frame(x=fold_x)
  fold_y_df = data.frame(y=fold_y)
  print(paste("number of rows in fold_x_df is ", nrow(fold_x_df), sep=" "))
  print(paste("number of rows in fold_y_df is ", nrow(fold_y_df), sep=" "))
  rf = randomForest(fold_x_df, fold_y_df, ntree=1000)
  print(paste("mse for fold number  ", " is ", sum(rf$mse)))
}

rf = randomForest(x_data, y_data, ntree=1000)
```

It gives me an error:

```
...The response has five or fewer unique values.  Are you sure you want to do regression?
```

I don't understand why it gives me that error.

I've checked these sources:

[Use of randomforest() for classification in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19301033/use-of-randomforest-for-classification-in-r) 
[RandomForest error code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20105480/randomforest-error-code)
https://www.kaggle.com/c/15-071x-the-analytics-edge-competition-spring-2015/forums/t/13383/warning-message-in-random-forest

None of those solved my problem.  you can look at the print statements, there are clearly more than 5 unique labels.  Not to mention, I'm doing regression here, not classification, so I'm not sure why the word "label" is used in the error.

Comment: The `y` argument to `randomForest` should be a vector, not a data frame. If you use `fold_y` instead of `fold_y_df` you'll be fine. (Or put `x` and `y` in the same data frame and use the `data` argument and the `formula` method.)

Comment: just the `y` argument?

Comment: Correct! Try it yourself and see!

Comment: The documentation specifies `x` as a matrix, but a data frame is easily coerced to a matrix. As random forests are almost always used with multiple predictors, it wouldn't make sense for `x` to be a vector. But as they are limited to a single response variable it doesn't make sense to have a whole data frame just for the response.

Comment: That's terribly inconvenient.

Comment: Really? Why? You seem to be going to a lot of extra trouble to put things in data frames. I would say your extra lines of code to put vectors into data frames look pretty inconvenient.

Comment: Two reasons why this was inconvenient:
1. The error message was hopelessly off-target.  
2.  indexing the rows of data frames with only one column does not result in another data frame - it results in an atomic vector.  But when there are two or more columns, for some reason indexing the rows does result in another data frame?  Why, I don’t know.

Comment: Yes, errors can be difficult to anticipate and error messages are often less than helpful. This is definitely an example of that. And yes, when you pull a single column out of a data frame, R's default assumes that you want the vector, not an n-by-1 data frame. Most of the time it's a good assumption, but you think about it so infrequently that it can really bite you when it's *not* what you want. You can keep it as a data frame by adding `drop = FALSE` to `[`, as in `fold_x_df  <- x_data[x_indices, , drop = F]` (as in "dropping unused dimensions").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is giving the response as a data frame. Since the response must be one-dimensional, it makes sense that it should be a vector. Here's how I would simplify your code to use the `data` argument of `randomForest` with the `formula` method to avoid the issue entirely:

```
  ## simulation: unchanged (but seed set for reproducibility)
library(randomForest)
n = 1000
factor=10
set.seed(47)
x1 = seq(n) + rnorm(n, 0, 150)
y = x1*factor + rnorm(n, 0, 550)

  ## use a single data frame
all_data = data.frame(y, x1)

  ## define the folds outside the loop
fold_ids <- cut(seq(1, nrow(x_data)), breaks = k, labels = FALSE)

for (nfold in seq(k)) {
    id_indices <- which(fold_ids == nfold)
      ## sprintf can be nicer than paste for "filling in blanks"
    print(sprintf("number of rows in fold %s is %s", nfold, length(id_indices)))
      ## just pass the subset of the data directly to randomForest
      ## no need for extracting, subsetting, putting back in data frames...
    rf <- randomForest(y ~ ., data = all_data[id_indices, ], ntree = 1000)
      ## sprintf also allows for formatting
      ## the %g will use scientific notation if the exponent would be >= 3
    print(sprintf("mse for fold %s is %g", nfold, sum(rf$mse)))
}
```